# how to update current time for a column called created_on in my postgres database using now () along with \copy from command

Tags: postgresql

I am loading `csv` file from my local `psql` to `postgres` database which is in a remote server using `\copy` . The problem is there is column called `created_on` it needs to updated to the system time whenever the records get updated but created_on has timestamp without time zone type with a not null constraint. So how can I load the `csv` file and at the same time set the `created_on` to now in one statement?

```
\copy counter_template(counter_name,category,counter_type_name,module_name,default_instance_name,query_string,execution_type,user_id,enterprise_id,created_by,display_name,unit) from 'F:\Work\test2.csv' with delimiter as ',' FORCE NOT NULL default_instance_name,query_string,execution_type HEADER csv;
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR:  null value in column "created_on" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (5470, hostname, status, null, Apache_Metricset, null, Application, f, f, null, f, f, 1, , f, , , f, 1, 0, f, null, null, 1, null, Hostname, keyword, f, f, f, 0, , f, null, f, null).
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `BEFORE INSERT` [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtrigger.html)
 on the table that [supplies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) the current time for `created_on`.

Comment: Sir can you please elaborate ??

Comment: I have added links to the documentation that should answer any questions. I am not a nobleman, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

> *So how can I load the csv file and at the same time set the
>     created_on to now in one statement?*

With a `DEFAULT` clause on the column.

```
ALTER TABLE counter_template ALTER COLUMN created_on SET DEFAULT now();
```

After that, each time a new row is inserted and there is no value specified for this column, be it with `COPY` or `INSERT`, the value will be filled based on this `DEFAULT` expression.